# Два двоеточия подряд?

Tags: пунктуация

Писала предыдущий вопрос про игрушки и зависла на знаках препинания. А именно, в этой фразе: "Нужно было написать вчера такую фразу, а я внезапно задумалась: как правильно — играть в игрушки или играть с игрушками?" По идее, после "задумалась" нужно двоеточие, но и после "правильно" оно просится. Может ли быть два двоеточия подряд?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все правильно Вы написали. При двух двоеточиях одно из них заменяется на тире.

Answer (score 4):

Может. Примеры таких предложений есть в произведениях русской  литературы.
**Справочник Лопатина:**

***В разных частях сложных синтаксических конструкций по условиям контекста могут оказаться два двоеточия, двоеточие и тире. При расстановке этих знаков учитываются их смысловая значимость и их возможная замена, которая создает условия для передачи смысловых оттенков и, следовательно, для вариантного употребления знаков.***

Если несколько частей сложного предложения последовательно ***связаны значениями причины, пояснения (возможна подстановка союзов потому что, а именно)***, то, вопреки общему правилу (и в том и в другом случае правила предусматривают постановку двоеточия), **возможна** замена одного из двоеточий знаком тире для передачи разных оттенков значения. Ср. примеры: *Было жалко Алпатову Гуська: с этим стариком связывалось всё лучшее в детстве и всегда казалось: из всех людей на свете нет лучше и нет роднее Гуська (Пришв.). — Было жалко Алпатову Гуська: с этим стариком связывалось всё лучшее в детстве и всегда казалось — из всех людей на свете нет лучше и нет роднее Гуська*. ...(двоеточие указывает на основное членение предложения, а тире является внутренним знаком).  [Далее читайте здесь](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=488)

Answer (score 2):

В Вашей фразе вместо первого двоеточия можно поставить запятую:  "Нужно было написать вчера такую фразу, а я внезапно задумалась, как правильно: играть в игрушки или играть с игрушками?"(оформить как сложноподчинённое предложение). А Ваше тире может быть объяснено как тире перед однородными членами в конце предложения. Но если замена невозможна, два двоеточия в одном предложении вполне корректны.